# 2 huge list all with same id needs to filter and get the distinct items only

Tags: java, list, filter, unique

I have 2 huge list where more than millions of items. I am not allowed to share the production code. But I can simulate the actual code by following. Where I have few same id and other different id. I would like to have a list that will have only distinct id elements. I have solved it using classic Java where no stream API used. In terms of performance it is good enough when I have millions of items. How can I improve this code:-

```
    public class TestClass {
    private String id;
    private LocalDate creationTimestamp;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getCreationTimestamp() {
        return creationTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate creationTimestamp) {
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
    }
}

    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    testClass.setId("1");
    testClass.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass();
    testClass2.setId("2");
    testClass.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass3 = new TestClass();
    testClass3.setId("3");
    testClass.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass4 = new TestClass();
    testClass4.setId("4");
    testClass.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());

    List<TestClass> testClassesList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    testClassesList1.add(testClass);
    testClassesList1.add(testClass2);
    testClassesList1.add(testClass3);
    testClassesList1.add(testClass4);

    TestClass testClass5 = new TestClass();
    testClass5.setId("1");
    testClass5.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass6 = new TestClass();
    testClass6.setId("2");
    testClass6.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass7 = new TestClass();
    testClass7.setId("5");
    testClass7.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());
    TestClass testClass8 = new TestClass();
    testClass8.setId("6");
    testClass8.setCreationTimestamp(LocalDate.now());

    List<TestClass> testClassesList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    testClassesList2.add(testClass5);
    testClassesList2.add(testClass6);
    testClassesList2.add(testClass7);
    testClassesList2.add(testClass8);


    List<TestClass> uniqueTestClasses = new ArrayList<>();

    if(testClassesList1.size() == testClassesList2.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testClassesList1.size(); i++) {
            if(testClassesList1.get(i).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    testClassesList2.get(i).getId())){
                uniqueTestClasses.add(testClassesList1.get(i));
            }else{
                uniqueTestClasses.add(testClassesList1.get(i));
                uniqueTestClasses.add(testClassesList2.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine. Also if the size is different, then what will be the solution? But it is not good in term of performance. How can I improve this to achieve the same goal with stream API.

Comment: If space complexity is not of concern then you can create a HashSet of the smaller list and then loop through the bigger list. For each element in bigger list check if that element exists in the HashSet. Theoretically, this should be O(n) runtime and O(n) space complexity as checking element in a HashSet is O(1) operation.

Comment: All logic like crating a HashSet out smaller list and then looping each element from the bigger list. And if element exist, I have to remove that element from the bigger list. All this check and removal is not working for me. I am new Java developer with not much experiences. Could you pls explain by the code snippet?

Comment: _Why_ are you keeping "millions" of items in a list instead of using something like a database?

Comment: I get it form some external service. I don't have any access to that external service. I think they use database to store those data. I have to display only the unique items when I get them by some api.

Comment: @Harsh No I am not concern about the time or space complexity that much. I need a efficient solution than the solution I have given. Also, I found that the way I did like checking size of both list. For my actual problem size could be same or different. Also, I am not experienced Java developer. I am still learning. So I can't code all the given instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for a code snippet of using HashSet method, below is one.

```
public List<TestClass> checker(List<TestClass> ls1, List<TestClass> ls2){
    
    //Creating HashSet to store ids
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    
    //Finding the smaller list
    List<TestClass> smallerList = ls1.size() <= ls2.size() ? ls1 : ls2; 
    List<TestClass> biggerList = ls1.size() > ls2.size() ? ls1 : ls2;
    
    //Adding smaller list values to the HashSet
    for(TestClass tc : smallerList)
        set.add(tc.getId());
   
    //Looping through bigger list and searching and removing data
    Iterator<TestClass> iter = biggerList.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        TestClass t = iter.next();

        //Checking if the object is in smallerList
        if(set.contains(t.getId()))
            iter.remove();
    }
    return biggerList;
}
```

I haven't tested this code out. It might have some syntactical errors.

Comment: Perfectly done not only syntax but also the logic. Thanks a lot!